# Which MDB listens on a Queue

Tags: queue, message-driven-bean

How can I tell which MDB is listening to a specific Queue, given the queue's name ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the queue manager. ActiveMQ, for example, has its web console where you can look up queue listeners. Other MQs have (or don't have) their tools.

Edit: I thought I'd add this: In WebsphereMQ you can check "queue handle status" for each queue, you can see how many clients from which Websphere Application Server instance listens. Tracking it down to particular MDB is difficult, as it only gives you server coordinates, and some human-unreadable binary ids.